# Using a buildroot created toolchain outside of Buildroot?

Tags: build, configure, toolchain, buildroot, uclibc

I'm trying to compile XFCE using Uclibc. Uclibc was generated by crosstool-ng via buildroot. How do i use the toolchain to build something outside of buildroot? I've had a look at the instructions on both buildroot's and uclibc's website and they were all a bit vague. Do i set a flag during ./configure with a link to uclibc? Or have i totally missed the point?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must pass --host and --build to the configure script, and set the PKG_CONFIG variable, at least. May require more tweaks (you can override the auto-detection using environment variables).

Why don't just add the required packages to buildroot?